# How to handle time difference in Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, timezone

In my Rails application I would like to store the `last_login` time of a user in a database. Then I would like to display the `last_login` time to user **based on his local time** (i.e. it should be X if user is in Canada now, and Y if user is in Australia now).

**Question 1**

How would you recommend to handle the time difference ? Should I store in database the `last_login` translated to UTC, and when displaying translate it again to the local time, or is there a better method ?

**Question 2**

How could I identify the local timezone for displaying the `last_login` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are right about storing `last_login_at` in UTC (or whatever server time is). It will be stored in that time by default. Then you can convert it to user local time:

```
user.last_login_at.in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)')
```

In Rails Api you can find more about [timezones](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html) and about [time with zone](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html).

To determine user timezone you can use some GeoIP tool, for example [this one](https://github.com/cjheath/geoip) (follow description there). But it's not 100% accurate detection. The most reliable way to ask user select his timezone when he signing up.

To collect all timezones you can run:

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.map(&:name)
```